# External router access without uPNP

Tags: networking, nas, port-forwarding

I have a Western Digital NAS device attached to my Linksys E2500 router. I would like to disable remote access to the MBL from outside my home network.  So I went to Settings/Remote Access and turned off the Remote Access checkbox. So far so good. To my surprise, after a few days, I opened up the WD My Cloud app from outside (on my iPhone using a cellular data connection) and I was able to browse the NAS! When I went back home, the Remote Access checkbox was enabled again.

Does a reboot or new firmware make the MBL forget that I had unchecked the box? How can I make the setting stick permanently?

More troubling...I went to my router (Linksys E2500) settings and turned *off* the uPNP feature on the router. I understand this is what enables the My Cloud app to go through my router from the Internet and set up automatic port forwards as neeed. I don't like this so I turned this off. So, with this turned off, how in the world is the iOS My Cloud app able to access the NAS from outside the home network?! This is really scary. The router does't show any ports forwarded, uPNP is turned off, so how is this possible?!

Comment: On the router, did you remember to click "Save Settings"? Did the router restart at that point? Linksys routers never remember settings changes until they restart.  And is it possible that you put the NAS into the router's DMZ?  uPNP is not the only way you can get to a device from outside; not much sense to using uPNP unless you are running a media server.

Comment: I did click Save Settings but I did not restart, will try that. No, the DMZ list on the router is empty, nothing in it. Right, DMZ, uPNP and manual port forwards are the only methods I know of to get to a device from outside and all 3 of them are disabled, hence my astonishment.